# Sum of prime values of Cyclotomic Polynomials of an integer evaluated at an integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials

$\Phi_n(x)$ is the nth cyclotomic polynomial evaluated at a specific integer $x$. The prime indicator function $\mathrm{Id}(n)$ is $1$ when $n$ is a prime number, $0$ otherwise.

What is the value of this sum?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{Id}\left( \Phi_n(x) \right) $$

Comment: Is there any reason to think it's not infinite? It certainly is for $x=1$.

Comment: Is there any reason to think it's infinite?

Comment: As I say, it is when $x=1$. Is there any value of $x$ for which you can prove it's finite?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: There could be many interesting stories here. For example the case $x=2$ is semi-related (but not equivalent) to infinitude of Mersenne primes. I'm not sure that there is an **answerable** question here.

Comment: Yeah I guess this is not standard enough of a question or something, should I just delete it then?